# Why does strace report my x64 FASM program runs in 32-bit mode?

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, fasm

I have `format ELF64 executable 3` at top of my source file.

I compiled my program using `fasm main.asm`

Output:

```
flat assembler  version 1.73.13  (16384 kilobytes memory, x64)
3 passes, 319 bytes.
```

Then I tried to run it using `strace ./main`, because it didn't work as expected and in output there is `strace: [ Process PID=3012310 runs in 32 bit mode. ]`.

`file main`: `main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, no section header`

`uname -m`: `x86_64`

Comment: That should not happen unless maybe your program itself is executing some other program and that is what's running in 32 bit mode. Of course that should be clear from strace output. You did not show any code, but what I tested works.

Comment: My program is not executing any other program. There are only basic syscalls i.e. `read`, `write`, `open`, `close` and `exit`.

Comment: Is the 32 bit message at the start of the strace output or do you have some syscalls logged before that?

Comment: Under this message there is only `restart_syscall` and `exit(1)`.

Comment: Show your code, does it include `BITS` anywhere?

Comment: By any chance are you using `int 0x80` (this is part of the compatibility layer on 64-bit versions of Linux built with IA32_COMPAT) to make system calls rather than `syscall` (The preferred mechanism to make 64-bit system calls?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It doesn't include `BITS` anywhere. Like I said in question, program is compiled as 64-bit, I'm **not** using any 32-bit registers, but still when I `mov rax, 0` it runs `restart_syscall` (32-bit behavior) instead of `read` (64-bit behavior).

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm using `int 0x80`. Is it only for 32-bit asm or both?

Comment: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code) TL;DR: don't.

Comment: Int 0x80 goes through the IA32_COMPAT layer. It is allowed in 64-bit code (if the Linux kernel is built with IA32_COMPAT support) but it only looks at the lower 32-bits of a 64-bit register. To make 64-bit system calls use the `syscall` instruction. Ryan Chapman has the Linux 64-bit system calls documented here in a table: https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: `int 0x80` is the x86 kernel interrupt call... `syscall` is the x86_64 call.

Comment: I checked now and it works with `syscall`. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Be aware that the system call numbers are different between int 0x80 and syscall and the parameters are passed in different registers.

Comment: I know about different numbers and registers. I only didn't know that I have to use something different than `int 0x80` for system call.

Comment: I can't tell that because you didn't present any code. When I was first to suggest `int 0x80` vs `syscall` I had to make an educated guess in the absence of seeing what calls you are making and what registers you used to pass things.

Comment: So, the program isn't actually running in 32-bit mode; presumably `strace` just assumes (wrongly) that any program using `int 0x80` is a 32-bit program.

Comment: @DeBos99: you don't need to avoid 32-bit registers in 64-bit mode.  In fact you should *prefer* them except for things that need to be 64-bit (sometimes pointers).  [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](//stackoverflow.com/q/38303333)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`

Answer (score 0):

**`strace` is wrong, your process isn't actually *running* in 32-bit mode, just using the 32-bit `int 0x80` system call ABI.**

You can check with `gdb ./main` and use `starti`.  `info regs` will show that the register state is 64-bit, including 16x 64-bit registers, not 8x 32-bit registers.  Or more simply, `layout reg`.

---

I see the same strace bug(?) when building a program with NASM that uses the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI in 64-bit mode to make an `exit` system call.

I added a delay loop before the first system call and I see `strace` doesn't print out the bitness of the target process until it makes a system call.  So **apparently `strace` infers that from whether it uses the 64-bit `syscall` ABI or the 32-bit `int 0x80` / `sysenter` ABI!**

[What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

Perhaps this is related to `strace` trying to figure out how to decode system calls: The Linux  `ptrace` API that `strace` uses doesn't have a simple reliable mechanism to tell which system call ABI a process invoked.  https://superuser.com/questions/834122/how-to-distinguish-syscall-from-int-80h-when-using-ptrace

A 64-bit process that uses 32-bit system calls used to just get decoded according to 64-bit call numbers.  But now it seems modern `strace` checks:

**I used `eax=1` / `syscall` to invoke `write`, and `eax=1` / `int 0x80` to invoke `exit`, and `strace` decoded them both correctly**

```
execve("./nasm-test", ["./nasm-test"], 0x7ffdb8da5890 /* 52 vars */) = 0
write(0, NULL, 0)                       = 0
strace: [ Process PID=5219 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

This is with `strace 5.3` on Linux 5.3.1-arch1-1-ARCH.